# Why isn't this asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, io, callback

I'm trying to get my around callbacks in nodeJS. I thought I had them down until I came across the following example:

```
 function async(callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    } 
    callback();    
}


async(function() {
    console.log('Expected 2nd Printout');
});

console.log('Expected 1st Printout');
```

My understanding of node and callbacks would be that after the async function has been invoked, "Expected 1st Printout" would be printed while we're waiting for the async function to finish executing then "Expected 2nd Printout" would be printed when it has finished. However, upon executing this simple program, the opposite occurs.

I'm thinking that because this is a processing task and not a situation where the async function is waiting for a file or listening for some network response that the program is run in a procedural way instead of an asynchronous way?

Comment: Why do you think this is asynchronous ? You are just passing the function and executing it right away. How will it be asynchronous ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the case with node.js, but Javascript is inherently single threaded. The fact that you've called the function `async()` does not cause it to run in another thread. Also, your empty `for` loop would almost certainly be optimised out by the JITter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use process.nextTick() to make your function asynchronous. Official documentation:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback

> Once the current event loop turn runs to completion, call the callback function. This is not a simple alias to setTimeout(fn, 0), it's much more efficient. It runs before any additional I/O events (including timers) fire in subsequent ticks of the event loop.

Also try to google for "Understanding the Node.js Event Loop" there are plenty of articles which will help you to understand what happens behind the scene.

Run this code:

```
function async(callback) {
    process.nextTick( function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log('i = ' + i);
        } 
        callback();
    });
}

async(function() {
    console.log('Expected 2nd Printout');
});

console.log('Expected 1st Printout');
```